# MariaDb: How to create a nested json object query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'd like to generate an array of json objects in MySql select query.

Here is a [db structure](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37ae9b/1) for which i'd like to return the result as below format.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shops` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

:: Update ::

The expected JSON output that would be return in postman:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "products": {
                "name": "product1"
            },
            "shops": {
                "name": "shop1"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "products": {
                "name": "product2"
            },
            "shops": {
                "name": "shop2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have searched for the same but can not get the result which is related to my topic so is it possible in **MariaDB** to create a query for rendering the above result ?

P.S: [DB Version](https://prnt.sc/sxnwrf)

Comment: Do you want to put both types in the samea array?

Comment: I have updated my question that would be return in postman, can you pls review ?

Comment: I still can't understand it. You have one output array, that is clear. But what are these objects with "products" and "shops" fields? whe there are two objects? Do you want to get shop and a list of products available at the shop?

Comment: The main aim is: need to render the records of `products` and `shops` table in individual objects and they are not dependent with each other. 
So, need to fetch them as first row records will be in first object of `product` and `shop`, then second, third and so on...

Comment: Why can't you use the query I've provided in my answer? It has one object with two fields: shop array and product array. You may add any other fields in there (like id that you would probably whant to add). You can change names, ordrs etc

Comment: Addad one more version, may be it is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely clear for me what you need to get, but

Here is something to start with:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    '{"shops": [', 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{"name": "', name, '"}') separator ","),
    ']}'
)
FROM shop;
```

That would produce this output:

```
{"shops": [{"name": "shop 1"},{"name": "shop 2"},{"name": "shop 3"}]}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    '{',
    (SELECT CONCAT(
        '"shops": [', 
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{"name": "', name, '"}') separator ","),
        ']'
    ) FROM shop),
    ',',
    (SELECT CONCAT(
        '"products": [', 
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{"name": "', name, '"}') separator ","),
        ']'
    ) FROM product),
    '}'
);
```

This will give something ghis:

```
{"shops": [{"name": "shop 1"},{"name": "shop 2"},{"name": "shop 3"}],"products": [{"name": "product 1"},{"name": "product 2"},{"name": "product 3"}]}
```

Now it is possible to mix that in anyway you want to get desired output.

Here is one more version:

```
SELECT CONCAT('{"data": [', GROUP_CONCAT(json, ""), ']}')
FROM (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{"shop": {"name": "', name, '"}}') separator ",") json
    FROM shop
    union all
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{"product": {"name": "', name, '"}}') separator ",") json
    FROM product
) t;
```

Which produces:

```
{"data": [{"shop": {"name": "shop 1"}},{"shop": {"name": "shop 2"}},{"shop": {"name": "shop 3"}},{"product": {"name": "product 1"}},{"product": {"name": "product 2"}},{"product": {"name": "product 3"}}]}
```

Comment: Sir, i have updated my question for better celerity that how the result will be return in postman.